# domain checker how to do suggestions?

Tags: php, mysql, dns

I have a basic domain checker that returns a 'this domain is free' or 'this domain is not available' message. But how do I make suggestions?

Lets say the visitor checks whether 'www.stackoverflow.com' is available. When it's available, there's no problem and the user can go order it. When it's not available, i want it to do suggestions for other extensions. Like:

```
www.stackoverflow.com is not available,

The following domains are available:
www.stackoverflow.net
www.stackoverflow.co.uk
www.stackoverflow.info
```

This is my current file:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['check'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['domain_name'])){
        $domain = trim($_POST['domein_naam']).$_POST['domain_list'];
        $result = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_ALL);

            if(empty($result)) {
                 echo "<H2 style='color:green;' >Domain $domain is available.</H2>";
            } else {
                echo "<H2 style='color:red;'>Domain $domain is not available.</H2>";
            }

     } else { 
     echo "<H2 style='color:red;'>Fout: Domein kan niet leeg zijn.</H2>";
     }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all of your code structure it's hard to give you the best method.
But a simple idea:

Say the site the user entered ($_POST/$_GET/etc) is stored in `$strUserSite` variable.

Have an array (`$aryFurtherChecks` or whatever) with all extensions in (.com, .net, etc).

Loop the array checking if each domain for what user entered is avail or not, by appending your `$strUserSite` var to it.
If domain + extension from array is available, either echo it out (depending on your code setup/framework etc) or add to new array, then loop second array with "These are also available".

Which methods you use depend on if you're using procedural all-in-one-file code, or classes etc.
If the latter then setting a new array would be preferred, looping it in your view/template/whatever file and echoing out each one with your HTML and styling etc.

Answer (score 0):

`dns_get_record()` cannot be used to determine whether a domain is available for registration, because not all registered domains have DNS records. For instance, `example.info` is registered, but has no DNS records.

Since it sounds as though you are planning to use this as part of a domain registration system, you presumably have access to a domain registration API. Most providers of such APIs have a call to generate suggestions - try using that. Failing that, you will need to remove the TLD from the domain input by the user and replace it successively with the alternatives you want to try.